# Is there a use for hooks_riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-hooks

I'm kinda confused as to what exactly the aim is with [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod), I've used [flutter_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod), and I've used [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks), but what is hooks_riverpod, on the pub.dev main page for hooks_riverpod, it's documentation is just flutter_riverpod documentation, there's not a single mention of hooks, and it's basically the same syntaxes and functionality?, I'm super confused, is this a troll package?, when I import hooks_riverpod into my project and remove flutter_riverpod, there are no errors, it just works with my former flutter_riverpod code. How and what is hooks riverpod and where is the documentation, how does it do anything different than flutter_riverpod since flutter riverpod basically even has full hook capabilities with extra features, what's the point of this combination and where is the evidence of the hooks added to the flutter_riverpod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flutter_hooks` package allows you to use hooks like: `useEffect`, `useState`, `useAnimation`, `useTextEditingController` and others. The full list is presented here [Existing hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks#existing-hooks).

---

As an example, we could use hooks to manually implement a fade-in animation, where a widget starts invisible and slowly appears.

If we were to use StatefulWidget, the code would look like this:

```dart
class FadeIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const FadeIn({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<FadeIn> createState() => _FadeInState();
}

class _FadeInState extends State<FadeIn> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController animationController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Opacity(
          opacity: animationController.value,
          child: widget.child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Using hooks, the equivalent would be:

```dart
class FadeIn extends HookWidget {
  const FadeIn({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final animationController = useAnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    );

    useEffect(() {
      return null;
    }, const []);

    useAnimation(animationController);

    return Opacity(
      opacity: animationController.value,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Note that we use the `HookWidget` class, which allows you to use hooks inside the `build` method. But at the same time, we do not have `WidgetRef ref` as an argument to the `build` method.

And it is the package `hooks_riverpod` that gives us the widget `HookConsumerWidget` that allows us to use hooks in the `build` method, and also has `WidgetRef ref` as an argument

```dart
class HomeView extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const HomeView({Key? key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // HookConsumerWidget allows using hooks inside the build method
    final state = useState(0);

    // We can also use the ref parameter to listen to providers.
    final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider);
    return Text('$counter');
  }
}
```

You can read more about it here

- [Extending HookConsumerWidget instead of HookWidget](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#extending-hookconsumerwidget-instead-of-hookwidget)
  or here in new documentation
- [About hooks](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/about_hooks).

Comment: So if I get it right, the hooks_riverpod lets you do hook stuff and riverpod stuff at the same time without having to instal the two packages separately?, so I can still do full riverpod stuff, and also do full hook stuff like useState, useEffect, all with one package?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you need hooks, use `hooks_riverpod` and `flutter_hooks`. If no hooks are needed, use only `flutter_riverpod`.

Answer (score 7):

You can always check the source code of an open source [package](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/tree/master/packages/hooks_riverpod/lib).

It is basically a re-export of `flutter_riverpod` with 3 additional classes which allow you to access the `WidgetRef` object and use hooks within the same widget.

- HookConsumerWidget
- StatefulHookConsumerWidget
- HookConsumer

Comment: but when using both a hook functionality and a riverpod one under the scope of a HookConsumerWidget, we still need to add the flutter hooks package separately?? because trying to use useState and ref.watch(someProvider) in the same build method says useState doesn't exist and expects me to import flutter_hooks separately

Comment: yes, you still need to add `flutter_hooks` to your `pubsepc.yaml` file and import it whenever you use hooks. `hooks_riverpod` does not re-export `flutter_hooks`.